# Pygithub Compare Commits on Single File

Tags: python, git, github, pygithub

Fairly new to github and python but was looking for a method for comparing commits on a single file via Pygithub.  I found this [compare(base, head)](http://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html) but that seems to compare two branches.

If I can't figure out how to do this in Pygithub I was going to consider the option of downloading the different file version and then utilizing the difflib to compare the two.

If anyone has any insights it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Brian